# Prevent Duplicates (mysql -u root -p TABLE < LOADFILE)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am migrating data from ServerA to ServerZ. As such I'm using mysqldump on ServerA and loading it into a table on ServerZ. Since the data I'm moving from the production ServerA changes (or remains unchanged), how do I ***prevent duplicates*** on ServerZ if I'm running [mysql -u root -p TABLE < LOADFILE] on an hourly basis with new updates I SCP over from ServerA?

Or should I simply delete the current data in the table and then load the new data.

### Sample Process:

```
Server A
In Crontab: 0 * * * * mysqldump -uroot -p --no-create-info  -R --triggers FOODATA > FOODATA.sql
In Crontab: 5 * * * * scp FOODATA.sql ServerZ:/var/tmp/
```

==

```
Server Z
In Crontab: 10 * * * * mysql -u root -p FOODATA < /var/tmp/FOODATA.sql
```

Comment: If you are migrating data why are you dumping data and loading it more than once? A migration implies you are moving things from ServerA to ServerZ. From your description it sounds like you are trying to create manual replication between the servers.

Comment: If your table have a primary key, then you will fall in an error when trying to put again the data that already exists on the table of **Server Z** because of duplicated key. So, try to add sentences to truncate the table on **Server Z** before inserting the updated data.

Comment: The reason for the multiple moves is because I'm effectively trying to keep ServerZ up to date as a type of mirror until production traffic is shifted from A to Z. In effect I'm creating a replication server on serverZ, but I cannot setup true replication because I have an issue with data on A that needs to be converted from MyISAM to InnoDB. And since I can't do that conversion in a replication setup, I need to perform this backwater mysqldump process.

Comment: It is entirely possible to replicate tables when one is MyISAM and the other is InnoDB.

Comment: 'cept in my case I'm moving MyISAM tables to MariaDB which need them to be InnoDB. So I have to have the incoming tables as InnoDB, yet I can't change the table on ServerA to InnoDB.  So I've got to mysqldump the table, convert it (using sed), xfer it to ServerZ, and then load it in.  If there is a way to setup replication that also does the conversion as part of the replication process, just let me know.

Comment: Define the table as InnoDB on ServerZ then set up replication. It will work just fine. We replicate a 50+ gig plus table this way. One side is MyISAM and the other side is MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks. Let me give that a shot and see how it pans out.

Comment: @Dave - Yes, it is OK to have different engines for the same table (on different servers), but you can't use Replication to initially populate a table.